# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x - 3}{\sqrt {x - 2} - \sqrt {4 - x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is to evaluate the given limit :

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x - 3}{\sqrt {x - 2} - \sqrt {4 - x}}$$

When I'm trying to evaluate this I'm getting $1$ as my answer but the answer given in the text is $0$.  I'm wondering how can this limit be equal to $0$.

I'm using $x = 3 + h$ (assuming $h$ is approaching zero) and now converting this limit in the form of $h$. Lim (h tends to zero) and substituting $x = 3 + h$.

In this way numerator equals $h$ and now after rationalizing the denominator I will get $2h$ and the numerator will also become $2h$ both of them will cancel each other and the limit will be equal to $1$.

I don't know where I'm going wrong. 
 Please edit if you can for proper reading because I don't know how to edit this in mathematical format.

Comment: $x+3 \to 6$ as $x \to 3$.  Did you mean $x-3$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Henry yeah the edited question looks the same. How can this limit be equal to 0. I'm solving it by right approach.

Comment: It must be $x-3$ in numerator.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah changes made.

Comment: For best results, please learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme yeah thanks for sharing the link I will learn it and will edit myself next time. Thank you.

Comment: You should also up vote answers that are helpful to you (once you have 15 rep) and [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one (at anytime) if it satisfies your question.

Comment: @probablyme yeah I was trying to upvote but I was unable to do so because I have less than 15 reps.

Answer (score 3):

We also have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x - 3}{\sqrt {x - 2} - \sqrt {4 - x}}&=\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x - 3}{\sqrt {x - 2} - \sqrt {4 - x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{(x-3)(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x})}{(x-2)-(4-x)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{(x-3)(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x})}{2x-6}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{(x-3)(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x})}{2(x-3)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x}}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3-2}+\sqrt{4-3}}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
&=\frac{2}{2}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Your working is correct. The answer is one. This is probably one of those cases where the textbook has a typo in it.

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{4-x}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h}-\sqrt{1-h}}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1-h})}{(\sqrt{1+h}-\sqrt{1-h})(\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1-h})}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1-h})}{2h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1-h})}{2}$$
$$=\frac{1+1}{2}$$
$$=1$$

Comment: That's exactly how I was solving it.  Apart from the question I just want to know how can I write my question in mathematical format like others have written their answers.

Comment: You mean how to type it here at Math.SE?

Comment: yeah I don't know how to write that way but now someone has shared a link the comments.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's wrong is the + sign in the numerator.  Most likely it should be a - sign as suggested by @Henry.

If I multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{4-x}$ I get a difference of squares in the new denominator, whose value cancels the $x-3$ factor.  Then I do in fact get 1.  0 and 1 are next to each other on a QWERTY board and somebody's finger slipped.

Comment: Yeah it's - in the numerator and I have edited it.